# jQuery Dynamic generate array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote jQuery code, That crawl object and then generate array , I try to generate array called "data" for autofill form and submit.
Note : Object length is different on any run.

```
var data = {};
$.each(
datasets,
function(item, dt) {
    console.log(item);     //Work Fine show me object Key
    console.log(dt['data'].join(",")); // Work Fine Show me object array value
    var name = item; //No problem
    var value = dt['data'].join(","); //No problem
    data.push({ name, value }); // Here i have Problem!!
    console.log(" data : ");
    console.log(data);
});
```

I try this but it can not detect "item"

```
data[item].push(dt['data'].join(","));
```

Comment: "// Here i have Problem!!" -> what problem?

Comment: data not fill i get : ` [Show/hide message details.] TypeError: data.push is not a function[Learn More]`

Comment: Oh, OK, missed it. `var data = []` is what you need. You want an array, not an object.

Comment: You are trying to push an array item into an object. Try `var data = []`

Comment: Great ! i change data = {} to data = [] it work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to use dynamic object and initialize 
We should define object like

```
var data ={};
```

Then for generate keys and initial value

```
data[name] = value;
```

Finlay , thanks for @SuperDJ for help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to add an Array item to an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

```
var data = {}; // {} is an object
```

The [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function can only be used to add items to an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

```
data.push({ name, value });
```

So change the variable to:

```
var data = []; // [] is an array
```

Comment: It's also interesting to me how can i save  name and value as object.

Comment: Do you mean adding items to object instead of array?

Comment: i try to make object like [link](http://labs.creative-area.net/jquery.formautofill/doc/#download)